# Why does Python operator.itemgetter work given a comma separated list of numbers as indices, but not when the same list is packaged in a variable?

Tags: python

Here is a demonstration of the issue I'm having.  I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something very obvious.

```
import operator

lista=["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
print operator.itemgetter(1,3,5)(lista)
>> ('b', 'd', 'f')

columns=1,3,5
print operator.itemgetter(columns)(lista)
>> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

How do I get around this issue so I can use an arbitrary list of indices specified as an argument at program start?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't about itemgetter, but about function calling syntax. These are different things:

```
operator.itemgetter(1, 3, 5)

operator.itemgetter((1, 3, 5))
```

The first one gets you item #1, item #3, and item #5. The second one gets you item #(1, 3, 5). (Which may make sense for a dictionary, but not for a list.)

The second one is what you get when you use `itemgetter(columns)`. So, how do you get the first?

```
operator.itemgetter(*columns)
```

That's it.

See [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a very useful aspect of the language I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass individual arguments to `itemgetter`. `columns` here is a tuple `(1, 3, 5)`  You can use the `*` operator to unpack it in the function call.  The `*` expands a list or tuple so that its values are sent as individual arguments, rather than passing the entire tuple as one argument.

For example: `func(*(1, 2, 3))` == `func(1, 2, 3)`

so what you need is:

```
columns=1,3,5
print operator.itemgetter(*columns)(lista)
```